# How to run npm script in maven which invokes rimraf, copyfiles and webpack commands

Tags: maven, jenkins, build, npm, webpack

I have the following script in my *package.json*

```
"clean": "rimraf dist/*"
"copy": "copyfiles -f ./src/index.html ./src/favicon.ico ./dist"
"dist": "npm run copy & webpack --env=dist"
```

and I would like maven build in Jenkins to execute the *dist* script. What plugins do I need for maven to be able to handle this? So, basically the Jenkins build builds back end and bundles the UI, and copies the UI artifact to webapp folder of the web application

Answer (score 0):

You can use the exec-maven-plugin to execute npm but you will need to have npm installed and available on your path:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <configuration>
                         <executable>cmd</executable>
                        <workingDirectory>${whatever Directory}</workingDirectory>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>/C</argument>
                            <argument>npm</argument>
                            <argument>dist</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
             </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I get the following error when plugin tries to execute npm: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application. Folder is correct and npm runs fine from command line